# Animating divs on load between two pages

Tags: jquery, css

I have two lots of the same divs on seperate pages - Is there a way to animate them to from the start position landing page to the postion on the 2nd page and open the first content div (blue) so basically animate left to make a vertical line instead of the cube.

so from here http://www.crazyedits.co.uk/

to here http://www.crazyedits.co.uk/home.php# and open the first coloured div?

I am just starting to learn so try to keep it simple peeps (sorry if my question is obvious) - but i have tried for 5 hours to find a solution and nothing seems to work.

landing page button

```
<div class="button1">
    <div id="icon"><img src="Images/home.png" width="200" height="160" /></div>
    <div id="title">HOME</div>
</div>
```

content page button

```
<div>   <div class="content_button1">
    <div ="icon"><a href="#home_page" ><img src="Images/home.png" width="200" height="160" style="border:none;" /></a></div>
    <div id="title"><li><a href="#home_page" >HOME</a></li></div>
    <div id="home_page" class="contain"></div> </div>
</div>
```

CSS

I think the issue i have is i have had to set 2 different css sets for the buttons on each page - one aligning them in the center and one aligning them left. So if there is a way that i could use the same class and still get the 4 in the square as they are and something to do with an absolute position then i would be a step closer to making it work

```
/******page buttons*******/

.content_button1{width:199px; height:199px; margin:0px 0px 19px 0px; background-color:#09C;} 
.content_button2{width:199px; height:199px; margin:19px 0px 19px 0px; background-color:#C00;} 
.content_button3{width:199px; height:199px; margin:19px 0px 19px 0px; background-color:#F60;} 
.content_button4{width:199px; height:199px; margin:19px 0px 19px 0px; background-color:#093;} 

/*****landing page buttons*****/

.button1{width:199px; height:199px; float:left; margin:20px ; background-color:#09C;} 
.button2{width:199px; height:199px; float:left; margin:20px ; background-color:#C00;} 
.button3{width:199px; height:199px; float:left; margin:20px ; background-color:#F60;} 
.button4{width:199px; height:199px; float:left; margin:20px ; background-color:#093;}
```

Comment: Not sure I completely understand your question but have you considered animating the css `position` using jquery (http://api.jquery.com/animate/)?

Comment: i have looked at it but having hardly used jquery before i am a little out of my depth. basically the 4 large squares on the main page - if any are clicked i would like them all to transition to the left of the page shown in the 2nd link above, and then open the corresponding color content(secondary mission atm) the primary is to get them to move over to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really make an animation between 2 pages wecause the page 2 is loaded in the browser and animation is done via JS. The best solution is to make your stuff in a single page and play with absolute position.

I write a piece of code that could be a little complicated, but I commented a lot, in order to explain you all the stuff.

The four square are first place at the center of the page and re positionned when you resize the window.

Then, when you click on one of four square, an animation is launched and the corresponding content appear.

After that, clicking on another square make appear the corresponding content.

Good luck !

http://fiddle.jshell.net/4SZXT/11/  <-- The code is here

Comment: Sorry i didn't see this solution yesterday also will help a lot thank you

Comment: Thank you for the code + even more so the explanations in it. I made some slight changes to the layouts and final resting places of the boxes and added the images and re-sized etc. Now it looks 90% of what i wanted it to and in the fiddle acts pretty much as i wanted.But I cannot get this working on the webpage (it's probably me missed something) i have added a link to jquery lib, the css and a file called cube.js but this didn't work. do i have to put the script in the html file? or is it something else i am missing? http://jsfiddle.net/4SZXT/33/

Comment: sorted it - installed firebug and it turned out everything was right - except for a space at the end of the code preventing it from being happy (thank you again @user1073122) now to go sort the rest of the content and layout out

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9FdKU/1/)

CSS

```
.button {width:199px; height:199px; position:absolute}
#top-left {background-color:#09C;} 
#top-rite {background-color:#C00;}
#bot-left {background-color:#F60;}
#bot-rite {background-color:#093;}

#top-left.pos  {left:50%; margin-left: -110px; top:0px; }
#top-rite.pos  {left:50%; margin-left: 110px; top:0px; }
#bot-left.pos  {left:50%; margin-left: -110px; top:220px; }
#bot-rite.pos  {left:50%; margin-left: 110px; top:220px; }​
```

You can see how the classes and IDs are structured in such a way that you can easily get the position to go left. If you want some slick animation effect to go with it, you might want to look at this: http://api.jquery.com/animate

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){

        $('#center_content').css('margin-top','0');
        $('#top-left').css('left','0').css('margin-left','0').css('top','10px');
        $('#top-rite').css('left','0').css('margin-left','0').css('top','220px');
        $('#bot-left').css('left','0').css('margin-left','0').css('top','430px');
        $('#bot-rite').css('left','0').css('margin-left','0').css('top','640px');
    });        
});​
```

Comment: That's pretty much what i was after to get me going the right direction - i shall now go play with animate and see where it leads. I can't vote it up bud as i have a feeble rep score at the mo - but thanks again